# In Textmate, how can I change the style of comment line?

Tags: textmate

When I select a line in Textmate and do the shortcut for comment line (command-L on Mac), it uses C-style comments (ie. /* ... */). How do I change it to use C++ style comments (ie. // ...). I am editing Javascript if that makes a difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in an open TM window:

- go to the ***control bar*** (at the very bottom)
- *click* the icon with an upper-case "L" in a gray circle (the Language
  icon), then
- *select* the language (*javascript*) from the pop-up that appears after
  you click (after you've done this, you should see *javascript* just to the left of the language icon)
- **cmd-/** (command + forward slash) will give you the language-appropriate comment symbol.

Comment: This is pretty much it, though I wanted to stay in Javascript mode. It turns out there are two Javascript modes--one that uses /* ... */ and one that uses //.

Comment: Thanks--i inadvertently picked up "C++" from the text of your question; i've amended my answer by replacing "c++" w/ "javascript" though. Having done that, the answer is identical. In the javascript bundle only the comment symbol "//" is in the language grammar, the other type is not, perhaps because (as i'm sure you're aware) it's can easily occur in regular expression literals and so the first type is the most often used.

Answer (score 0):

Under default bindings, `Cmd-L` brings up the Go to line popup in Textmate.

In Textmate 2 alpha (.9561), with Javascript or C, you can use:

1) `Cmd-/` for line commenting (Bundles->Source->Comments->Comment Line):

- current line

`// cursor on this line`

- All selected lines

`// all these`

`// lines were`

`// selected`

- commenting from selection to end of line

On this line, only the string of hashes `// ###### was selected`

2) `Cmd-Opt-/` for block commenting selection (Bundles->Source->Comments->Insert Block Comment)

`/* all`

`these`

`lines`

`were`

`selected */`